# Wordpress SQL query to search and replace string

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to replace the following string in my Wordpress database:

```
[wpai_google_translate_text({./@name},{description[1]/short[1]},"en")]
```

I tried the 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/' plugin but it wasn't able to handle the above string.

I also tried some of the other solutions on Google such as the following command in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_content LIKE '%TEXT-TO-FIND-GOES-HERE%');
```

But that just searches from post contents.

The text I'm trying to replace doesn't reside in a post or page or any sort of user generated content.

So my question is, how can I search across my entire database and for that string and replace it with something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Close but you have the wrong query. Try:

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = valueForField WHERE post_content LIKE '%TEXT-TO-FIND-GOES-HERE%';`

Comment: @RahilWazir Becuase OP wants to change an existing field in his db

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress database is just a MySQL database. You need to issue this SQL query in order for you to search and replace text

```
update [table_name] set [field_name] replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

if you have phpmyadmin or if you're doing it on the command line, you can edit the query above and run it. be careful when editing, it can replace your entire database with the wrong string if you're not careful.

Comment: The thing is though, I have no idea which table or field the text resides in. I thought that there was a general query where I just insert the text to search for and the text to replace with. Sorry for the noob question

Comment: lol thats ok, all the information you need to modify are in wp_posts table. do a mysqldump or export the wp_posts table before you do anything. when you backup or export, you should have a wp_posts.sql file

Comment: So what field_name should I use then in this case?

Comment: post_content is the field where it stores the content

Comment: here is a diagram that will help: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/97/WP3.8-ERD.png locate where it points to wp_posts, you should see all other field types